# Laravel Thujohn Twitter API - Call the API on behalf of your users

Tags: php, api, twitter, laravel-5, autologin

I'm working with the framework Laravel 5, and I'm using Thujohn Twitter API everything was OK until I tried to call the API on behalf of my users.

I want to get information about users with their token a secret that I saved into the database.

First I get the users from the database that I haven't updated yet.

```
$user = TwitterUser::where('last_update', '<', new DateTime('today'))->orWhere('last_update', null)->whereNotNull('oauth_token')->first();
```

Then I get his tokens:

```
$request_token = [
'token'  => $user->oauth_token,
'secret' => $user->oauth_token_secret,
];

$eje = Twitter::reconfig($request_token);
$token = Twitter::getAccessToken();
$credentials = Twitter::getCredentials();
```

I can't make it work, I get this error message:

> [2015-09-01 00:12:28] local.ERROR: exception 'Exception' with message 'Invalid request token.' in /home/turpialdesign/tuitherramienta/vendor/thujohn/twitter/src/Thujohn/Twitter/Twitter.php:197

Comment: did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I later found out I was storing the wrong tokens thus wrong tokens when re configuring. If you check the Github repo (https://github.com/thujohn/Twitter) the tokens you should store (to use later) are the ones gotten after

```
$token = Twitter::getAccessToken($oauth_verifier);
```

thus;

```
'access_token' => $token['oauth_token'],
'token_secret' => $token['oauth_token_secret']
```

In my case I was storing the ones from the session which was wrong i.e

```
'access_token'  => Session::get('oauth_request_token'),
'token_secret' => Session::get('oauth_request_token_secret')
```